# JavaScript - Arbitrary Sort

Tags: javascript

I have an array like this:

```
var data = ['High', 'Low', 'Medium'];
```

This data array is created dynamically. So, it may have all 3 values or only 2 values or 1 value.

Regardless of the values in the array, I would like the array to be sorted in this fashion:

```
 var sortedArray = ['High', 'Medium', 'Low']
```

I have tried something like this:

```
var sortedArray = []
for(var 0;i<data.length;i++)
{
   if(data[i] = 'High')
    {
       sortedArray.push('High');
    }
   else if(data[i] = 'Medium')
    {
       sortedArray.push('Medium');
    }
    else if(data[i] = 'Low')
    {
       sortedArray.push('Low');
    }
}
```

How can we achieve that?

Comment: What did you try? And what logic is behind the desired result? I see none that a computer can determine. The array elements may mean something to a human, but a machine has no idea how you want to sort that.

Comment: do you have other than the mentioned values in the array?

Comment: @nina scholz nope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start with the complete array already sorted, and [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) out the elements that aren't in `data`.

```js
var data = ['Low', 'High'];

var sortedArray = ['High', 'Medium', 'Low'].filter( el => data.includes( el ) );

console.log( sortedArray );
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var data = ['High', 'Low', 'Medium'];

// create a dictionary to map each possible value
var map = {High: 3, Medium: 2, Low: 1, Default:0 };

// then sort

var sorted = data.sort((a,b)=>(map[a]||map.Default)>(map[b]||map.Default)?-1:1);

console.log(sorted);
```